# Change orientation of image after decoding

Tags: ios, swift, image

While assigning a decoded image to imageview, the image becomes incorrectly oriented.

This is how its assigned to an imageview..

```
 @IBAction func imageClicked(_ sender: Any) {

    if let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: result, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) {

          let image = UIImage(data: decodedData)
          myImageView.image = image
    }

}
```

It's not that the image has a wrong orientation always. Sometimes the orientation is fine while sometimes its oriented incorrectly. How can I fix this..? Went through many SO posts..but didn't get the desired results yet..

**EDIT 1** This is how I compress it to base64

```
let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.6)
 let compressedJPGImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)
 let img_Data = compressedJPGImage?.toBase64()
```

It is this image data that I'm saving to db.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213242/discussion-on-question-by-user13032222-change-orientation-of-image-after-decodin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is probably in your toBase64 method. It is probably converting your image to PNG data representation before encoding it. You can simply use Data's method `base64EncodedString()` directly in your JPEG data to encode its representation into a base 64 encoded string.

```
if let result = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.6)?.base64EncodedString() {
    // save your string to your database
}
```

Comment: Thanks again @Leo Dabus..:)